# Why is my console saying 404 not found for my css and javascript fiels that are not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, console

I have a folder in a folder that contains an article for my website and my main CSS and JavaScript files are outside of that folder and in the main folder when I use `<script src="script.js"></script>` and
`<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`
to get my CSS and JavaScript files so they can work and display on my webpage they do not display. I looked in my console and found a 404 not found error for my CSS and JavaScript files. I found out that they are trying to take a file that does not exist out of the same folder the article is in but they should be taking it from the main folder. `GET http://localhost/speedcode` ***/articles/*** `script.js`
and same for CSS. I want to get the file out of my main folder without putting `http://localhost/speedcode/script.js` (the full website address), or creating a new file.

---

sorry if my title is misleading or does not say the correct problem.
[image: my console]

Comment: were are located your `css` and `js` files in your server?

Comment: You have to use absolute paths in your headers. for example use `<script src="/dir/script.js">` not `<script src="dir/script.js">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your file structure correctly the `script.js` and `style.css` are in the parent directory of your html file.

For accessing the parent directory use `<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`, same for your `script.js`.

If you want to use a relative path `./` stands for the current and `../` for the parent directory. You can stack it like `../../someOtherDirectory/` to navigate to more complex relativ paths.